# Cannot open Filetype in Program Automatically, can't select program as default Program

Tags: windows-7, windows

so I have an issue.

I'm trying to get my .MPQ files in this folder to open with the MPQEditor program on my desktop.

[image]

The problem is, whenever I try to get an .MPQ file to use MPQEditor as it's default application, it won't allow me to do so, whenever I select it in the dialog below, it often selects Bittorrent as the default program, although I search for MPQEditor in the dialog -- almost as if it isn't carrying out what I've asked, even though MPQEditor is a valid program.

I added another association to test (Setup Application) and that worked as intended, but I HAVE had MPQEditor as the default program in the past so it's not an issue with the application itself.

[image]

Going to control panel and trying to choose default programs that way doesn't fix the issue, as it brings up this same Dialog, leading to the same case of being unable to select MPQEditor.

**Resolved:**

Had to go to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.cpp

and delete associated files that way.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**

Had to go to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.cpp